# How to get correct ngfor index/row number value based on condition

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, ngfor, angular-ng-if, row-number

I've over simplified this but lets say I have a table Persons in my database and I've fetched all of the records from the table. How can I show only employed persons in Angular table with correct row number.

*Also I know that I can fetch only employed persons directly from database in this case, but as I said this is just example for stuff I need*

Table persons from database

```
Person   |   employed
Mike        no     
Angela      yes     
Josh        yes     
Tim         no     
Michelle    yes
```

**I need this result:** Because I don't really want index value, I want table row number

```
RowNum |  Person 
 1        Angela 
 2        Josh   
 3        Michelle
```

The result I'm getting

```
RowNum |  Person 
 2        Angela 
 3        Josh   
 5        Michelle
```

This is the code:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>RowNum</th>
  <th>Person</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of persons; let i = index;">
     <ng-container *ngIf="item.employed == 'yes'">
        <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Person}}</td>
     </ng-container>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I know why this is happening so I've tried few versions of manually incrementing counters but with no luck...I didn't expect this is the thing I'll have problems with...

Comment: Its happening because: `index: number`: The index of the current item in the iterable.

Comment: HI, I'm aware of that, I need row number not exactly index value

Comment: `NgForOf` provides only 8 exported values that can be aliased to local variables. `https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables` displayIndex is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not filter first and after that iterate over array?

I mean

```js
let employedPersons = persons.filter(e => e.employed == 'yes');
```

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let item of employedPersons; let i = index;">
     <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
     <td>{{item.Person}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hi, because in real problem I have an object which has list of objects inside of it, and another list of objects inside of those objects....
So I practically have to show three different tables in frontend from 1 object

Comment: This is the most accurate way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

create a copy of your original array object and add rowNum property with it with different row numbers for employed and unemployed persons, that way you  could get different value for row for employees and not employees

```js
let employedCounter = 0;
let unemployedCounter = 0;
this.modifiedPersons = this.persons.map(person => {
    if (person.employed == 'yes') {
        employedCounter = employedCounter + 1;
        return { ...person, rowNum: employeedCounter };
    } else {
        unemployedCounter  = unemployedCounter + 1;
        return { ...person, rowNum: unemployeedCounter };
    }
});
```

and replace your persons with modifiedPersons

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of modifiedPersons; let i = index;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.employed">
        <td>{{ item.rowNum }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.person }}</td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```